# Ограничить пользователей ресурсами

Tags: highload, производительность, limits, linux

Есть linux, пользователи пользуются ресурсами данной машины. Но делают это, не понимая, что сервер один на всех )) и грузят его максимально тем самым мешая друг другу.

Дано: Виртуалка CentOS6.3 x64, 4GB RAMВот имею примерно такой вывод atop по самым пожирателям.

```
NPROCS   SYSCPU    USRCPU   VSIZE    RSIZE   RDDSK    WRDSK  RNET   SNET   CPU  RUID 1/155    0.05s     1.88s   14.6G   877.6M      0K       0K     ?      ?   39%   user156    0.06s     0.45s   12.8G   603.1M      0K      32K     ?      ?   19%   user257    0.01s     0.04s   12.0G   594.8M      0K      24K     ?      ?   11%   user3 3    0.00s     0.00s  401.9M    6632K      0K       0K     ?      ?    0%   user4
```

Хочу в /etc/sucurity/limits.conf зарезать немного их аппетиты, но пока выходит не очень.хочу кол-во процессов на юзера сделать soft/hard - 50/65, уменьшить значение VSIZE (virtual memory?), RSIZE (real memory?), и чтобы не жрали USRCPU (значение задается в минутах, т.е. как я понимаю сейчас значение 1.88s = это 1 минута 88сек??? а почему не 2.28s в любом случае процессор надо лимитировать)

Все пользователи входят в группу @domainusers, при попытке дать лимиты этой группе понял что это неверно т.к. все лимиты делятся пропорционально на зашедших в систему юзеров и в итоге хватает ресурсов только на одного.. ))

Остается только пологинно перечислять всех в limits.conf

```
user1  soft         nproc   50user1  hard         nproc   65user1  soft         cpu     1user1  hard         cpu     2user1  soft         as   1500000user1  hard         as   2000000user1  soft         rss  400000user1  hard         rss  500000....user2 ....
```

p.s. "as" как говорит ([гугл](http://shortrecipes.blogspot.ru/2009/04/limitsconf-virtual-memory-limit.html)) это и есть виртуальная память

Все ли я верно делаю?

P.S. эксперименты с limits.conf не внушают мне надежды. Когда лимиты подходят к своему пределу система становиться нестабильна и доходит до выпадания в корку. К примеру тупо не хватает свободных процессов, чтобы открыть вкладку и, к примеру, браузер рушиться в этот момент какая-нибудь дебаг-тулуза хочет отправить отчет и тоже валится и все крайне нестабильно начинает существовать.

P.P.S. Начал разбирать тему с [cgroups/cgrules](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/ru-RU/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/Resource_Management_Guide/index.html) - этот механизм вроде более жизнеспособен.

Comment: тоже очень интересен ответ, если найдете самостоятельно, то запостите здесь пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант: [PAM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_Authentication_Modules) и его [limits.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf)

Answer (score 1):

cgroup самый правильный и скорее всего единственный инструмент в linux-e для этого